# trim JSON object value

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json

I have form that gets JSON data from API by click of button and takes the value and present it as text of asp:label

The JSON data I'm getting:

```
[{"Name":"Tom",date":"2018-02-24T01:52:56.3229211Z"}]
```

My code like:
Body (just the important part):

```
<body>
    <h2 class="auto-style3">SPACCO WEB</h2>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" class="auto-style1">
    <asp:Label ID="info1"    runat="server"  Text="Name:"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="info1Val" runat="server"  Text=""></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="info2"    runat="server" Text="Date:"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="info2Val" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    <br />
</body>
```

The importance here is the that I'm putting the data as `text=""`  inside the `ID=info2val`

The Script:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#search').click(function () {
            $.ajax({

                url: "http://192.168.5.37/api/find/" + $("input#manualuser").val(),
                type: "GET",
                dataType: 'Jsonp',
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#<%=info2Val.ClientID%>').html(result[0].Name);
                    $('#<%=info3Val.ClientID%>').html(result[0].Data);
                }
            });
        })
```

**Result**:

```
Name: 
Tom

Date:
2018-02-24T01:52:56.3229211Z
```

**Problem:**
Everything working as expected but my problem is that I want to trim the date value to presented as : 2018-02-24 (and cut everything from **T** 01:52:56.3229211Z)

Please assist how can I do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the index of T in your date and then use substring.

```
var date = // Put your date here
var index = date.indexOf('T')
if (index != -1) {
  var shortened = date.substring(0, index)
}
```